# Cannot create Solr core on localhost - ERROR: Connection reset

Tags: macos, solr

I'm running Solr 8.2 on OSX 10.13.5. The Solr dashboard is accessible in my browser (via http://localhost:8983), yet when I run the terminal command "bin/solr create -c test" to create a core, after a few moments I end up with:

`ERROR: Connection reset`

I've tried booting Solr as sudo, and the result is the same. I'm at a bit of a loss here. How can I resolve this connection error and create a core? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It turns out that port 8983 was still in TIME_WAIT mode. I obtained the port's PID with:

```
sudo lsof -i :8983
```

Then closed the port with:

```
kill PID
```

Where 'PID' is the numerical PID of the port. With the port now being free of traffic, the core creation worked just fine. I'm leaving this posted in case any other Solr beginners hit this snag!